# combobox change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I can't undertand what are I am missing to fire my "change" event in a combobox.

I tried some different options I found in some post, but noone works, so, I think I'm missing something

My html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="es">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <body>
          <select class="myCombobox" id="myId">
            <option value="A">Opt A</option>
            <option value="B">Opt B</option>
          </select>
      <script>
          myJs.init();
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js:

```
var myJS = (function() {

var module = {};

module.initCombo = function(){
   $('.myCombobox').combobox( {      
      change: function( event, ui ) {
         console.log(ui);
         var selected_value = ui.item.value;
         alert("You selected : "+selected_value);
     }
   });
};

module.init = function() {

  module.initCombo();
};

return {
    init: module.init
};
```

})();

Why is the cange event not launched?

Comment: yes, I am, the combobox starts, but not the event

Comment: Do you have a reference to the specific plugin you are using?

Comment: its jquery.easyui.min.js, from jquery

Comment: Not every plugin that starts with "jQuery" is **from** jQuery, btw.

Comment: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#  The document for combobox doesn't have a 'change', but it does list an 'onChange'.